# Как задать минимальное число символов запроса в поле поиска в php скрипте-обработчике?

Tags: php

Есть форма поиска и скрипт-обработчик этой формы. Нужно как-то задать минимальное число символов в запросе (не менее 3), а то он выводит все результаты даже если ввести 1 символ (например, «а»)? Может быть как-то через if else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принцип такой:

```
<?php

$str = $_POST['str'];

if (mb_strlen($str) < 3) {
    die('Слишком короткий тект сообщения!');
} elseif (mb_strlen($str) > 1000) {
    die('Слишком длинный тект сообщения!');
}
```

Возможно ещё понадобится в ф-цию mb_strlen() дописать вторым параметром кодировку. Или же, если кириллица не используется, то заменить на strlen().

Comment: Большое спасибо. То, что нужно!